# How to write a query which finds all circular references when a table references itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key

I have the following schema (names changed), which I cannot change:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES MyTable(Id);
```

That is, each record is a child of another record. If a record’s `ParentId` is equal to its `Id`, then the record is considered a root node.

I want to run query which will find all circular references. For example, with the data

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, ParentId) VALUES
    (0, 0),
    (1, 0),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 3);
```

the query should return

```
Id | Cycle
2  | 2 < 4 < 3 < 2
3  | 3 < 2 < 4 < 3
4  | 4 < 3 < 2 < 4
```

I wrote the following query for SQL Server 2008 R2, and I am wondering if this query can be improved:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results;
CREATE TABLE #Results (Id INT, HasParentalCycle BIT, Cycle VARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @i INT,
    @j INT,
    @flag BIT,
    @isRoot BIT,
    @ids VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT Id
    FROM MyTable;

OPEN MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @i;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Parents') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Parents;
    CREATE TABLE #Parents (Id INT);

    SET @ids = NULL;
    SET @isRoot = 0;
    SET @flag = 0;
    SET @j = @i;
    INSERT INTO #Parents (Id) VALUES (@j);

    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @j = ParentId,
            @isRoot = CASE WHEN ParentId = Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Id = @j;

        IF (@isRoot = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @flag = 0;
            BREAK;
        END        

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Parents WHERE Id = @j)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Parents (Id) VALUES (@j);
            SET @flag = 1;
            SELECT @ids = COALESCE(@ids + ' < ', '') + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) FROM #Parents;
            BREAK;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Parents (Id) VALUES (@j);
        END        
    END

    INSERT INTO #Results (Id, HasParentalCycle, Cycle) VALUES (@i, @flag, @ids);

    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @i;
END
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;

SELECT Id, Cycle
FROM #Results
WHERE HasParentalCycle = 1;
```

Comment: The `0 > 0` should not be considered a cycle?

Comment: No, 0 is a root node, since its `ParentId` equals its `Id`, so it is not a cycle for this scenario.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This calls for a recursive CTE:

```
WITH FindRoot AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentId, CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Path
    FROM dbo.MyTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.Id, P.ParentId, C.Path + N' > ' + CAST(P.Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM dbo.MyTable P
    JOIN FindRoot C
    ON C.ParentId = P.Id AND P.ParentId <> P.Id AND C.ParentId <> C.Id
 )
SELECT *
FROM FindRoot R
WHERE R.Id = R.ParentId 
  AND R.ParentId <> 0;
```

See it in action here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a3f/4)

---

Update:

Added distance to be able to exclude all self cycles (see ypercube's comment):

```
WITH FindRoot AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentId, CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Path, 0 Distance
    FROM dbo.MyTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.Id, P.ParentId, C.Path + N' > ' + CAST(P.Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), C.Distance + 1
    FROM dbo.MyTable P
    JOIN FindRoot C
    ON C.ParentId = P.Id AND P.ParentId <> P.Id AND C.ParentId <> C.Id
 )
SELECT *
FROM FindRoot R
WHERE R.Id = R.ParentId 
  AND R.ParentId <> 0
  AND R.Distance > 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14417b/4)

Which one you should use depends on your requirement.

Comment: This should be corrected. Currently it also shows 1-cycles, like `6 > 6`, as long it is not `0 > 0`.

Comment: I understood the OP that only the actual root nodes self cycle is to be excluded. You can however easily add that requirement by checking that R.Path like '%>%' in the final where clause. Or you could add a cycle length count column inside the recursive CTE.

Comment: You could just add `WHERE Id <> ParentId` in the first part of the CTE.

Comment: `AND C.ParentId <> C.Id` is not enough. It a path leads into a longer circle (`A->B, B->C, C->B`), you'd still get infinite recursion for constructing the paths starting in `A`. You'd really need to check for the entire path.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name
, KF.TABLE_SCHEMA FK_Schema
, KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
, KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
, RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name
, KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema
, KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
, KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
, RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption
, RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule
, RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE KF.TABLE_NAME = KP.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: And how does this work?  It's usually the explanation that makes a good answer.  Code-only posts are frowned upon here (usually, at least).

Comment: This looks like it answers a similar but different question.